# Tab Bar View Controller with table view on one tab

Tags: ios, xcode5, tableview, tabview

I have a 3 tab view controller.  One of the tabs has a table view retrieved from a JSON request/response.  When I initially go to this tab, the table loads fine from the viewDidLoad.  But when I go to another tab and come back to the table view tab, it still has the old table values. i want to make another JSON request and display the response.  How do I request another JSON request when the use comes back to this tab?

Comment: You should try putting your JSON request in viewWillAppear, not viewWillLoad.  Try that.

Comment: I meant viewDidLoad!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Douglas said in the comment, add your reload-function in the viewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self reloadMyData];
}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted my code from viewDidLoad to viewWillLoad and I do see it requests/receives JSON array and it stores it in a local NSArray for my table view.  However, it does not update the table view on the screen.  Any ideas? @Benjamin Herzog

Comment: Not to the viewWillLoad but the viewWillAppear or was that a typo in your comment?

Comment: Yes it was a typo in my code.  sorry.  I mean viewWillAppear.  Do I need to call something to reload the table view with the array.  I am updating the same NSArray that was used in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ok, so at the end of the viewWillAppear (when your data-array is full with the needed content) call this: [self.tableView reloadData];    This sends your tableView the message to call all the dataSource methods again. Like the numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection and the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I get an error saying tableView not found.  Please advise. @Benjamin Herzog

Comment: Is your tableView in a UITableViewController? If not, you have to send this message to the property of the tableView, it's name could be something else.

Comment: I have a Viewcontroller and I added a TableView into the view controller and set the datasource and delegate to the view controller.  So I am not sure where to get the tableView name? @Benjamin Herzog

Comment: Just add also a property of the TableView to your ViewController and there you give it a name you can use in the code